# How is the electrolyte stored in an Alkaline Fuel Cell?

Tags: chemical-engineering, energy-storage

Every type of fuel cell has a catalyst and an electrolyte to carry electrons between the cathode and anode. What I don't understand is how the electrolyte is stored in a Alkaline Fuel Cell. In essence, is the electrolyte stored as a liquid in a tank with the electrodes at either end of the fuel cell, or in some sort of sponge that is soaked in the electrolyte and then periodically re-wet with additional electrolyte?

**How is the electrolyte stored in an Alkaline Fuel Cell?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research of my own, I've found that Alkaline fuel cells tend to store the electrolyte as a liquid in a very thin layer (around 1.2-1.7mm in thickness) which can have some sort of solid polymer matrix or other shape to maintain its shape and structure.

I also found that the electrolyte is normally a free-flowing liquid, so a pump and reservoir is often used to circulate the electrolyte.

Reference 1 - https://arrow.tudublin.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1027&context=engscheleart2